# R markdown - \FloatBarrier equivalent

Tags: r, latex, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

Hopefully this is quick and easy question. Is there an equivalent in R Markdown, either as a latex imbed or a chunk option for a float barrier for images / R output, as in `\FloatBarrier` ?

Obviously, I could compile the doc in LaTeX, but I'm hoping to do it quickly and easily via markdown.

Answer (score 1):

R Markdown allows embedding [raw HTML](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_pandoc_markdown.html#raw-html) or [raw Tex](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_pandoc_markdown.html#raw-tex). As is typical for Markdown, it does not appear to provide that level of control natively.

[Custom CSS](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html#appearance-and-style) can also be specified for the output HTML.